# Refresh Control - showing above TV

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I'd like to ask you how can I show UIActivityControl under TV cells. This is how it's showed right now. Thanks

(self.tableView.refreshControl = self.refreshControl **doesn't work**)

Code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    self.refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Aktualizace")
    self.refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: "refresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    self.view.addSubview(self.refreshControl)
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.tableView)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the refresh_control member, nor do you need to add refresh_control as a subView.

UITableViewController has a refreshControl member.

Try this:

```
self.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
self.refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Aktualizace")
self.refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: "refresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```