# RefreshControl doesn't hide

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, refresh

My refresh control doesn't disappear after the refresh progress is done. It remains animating, even though I call endRefreshing().

```
import UIKit

class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl?.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
        refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.refresh), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
        tableView.addSubview(refreshControl!)

        setData()
    }

    func setData(){
        ApiClient.sharedInstance().getData{(myData, error) in
            if (myData != nil){
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.myLabel.text = myData
                    self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
                }
            }

            if (error != nil){
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }

    func refresh(sender:AnyObject) {
        setData()
    }

}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: You need to call endRefreshing on the main thread.

Comment: isn't this already done with "DispatchQueue.main.async {"?

Comment: Does `self.myLabel.text` update?

Comment: Async is the background thread. Change it to the main thread/dispatch_get_main_queue syncronously

Comment: Oh, I think I got it: when I release my finger, the circle disappears. But when I keep my finger down, the indicator remains animating, even when the refresh was done. But apparently (as in contacts- and mail.app), hiding the indicator before releasing the finger is not intended... Can you approve this? - To achieve an effect like in WhatsApp, for example, I think I'm just gonna hide the indicator with refreshControll.isHidden

Comment: add a breakpoint to the line of `self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()`, is it reachable?

Comment: yes, it is reached... How should the ".endRefreshing()" Function normally behave? Does the indicator also disappear, when you do not release the finger?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33136577/refresh-control-showing-above-tv/33620539

Comment: @Pascal endRefreshing between beginUpdates and end updates did the job. thanks for hint 

Answer (score 1):

beginUpdates and endUpdates did the magic.

This one drove me crazy for 1 hour. Finally this piece worked when my network call completes and refresh the table view.

```
 class TransactionsViewConttroller : MyBaseTableViewController{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh), for: .valueChanged)
    }
    @objc func refresh() {
        justRefreshTransactions()  
    }

    private func justRefreshTransactions(){
         ServiceRequest.getLatestTransactions(completionBlock : {(error, errorMsg,result) in 
                 self.stopRefrshIndic()
         })
    }

    private func stopRefrshIndic(){
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
            self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
            self.tableView.endUpdates()
        }
    }
```

}